# MongoDB Container Fails Windows 10

Tags: windows, mongodb, docker

I've checked around and I haven't *found* this issue yet on stack overflow.  If you find it; link it and I'll close this one.

Environment:

- Windows 10 (latest) 5/6/2019
- C Drive Shared
- Executed cmds from admin console

Action:

```
docker run -d -p 27017:27017 -v C:/data/mongo:/data/db --name mongo mongo
```

Expected Results:

Mongo container to be running in background.

What happens:

Failure with below logs

```
2019-05-06T16:28:25.980+0000 I STORAGE  [initandlisten] wiredtiger_open config: create,cache_size=2583M,session_max=20000,eviction=(threads_min=4,threads_max=4),config_base=false,statistics=(fast),log=(enabled=true,archive=true,path=journal,compressor=snappy),file_manager=(close_idle_time=100000),statistics_log=(wait=0),verbose=(recovery_progress),
2019-05-06T16:28:26.525+0000 E STORAGE  [initandlisten] WiredTiger error (1) [1557160106:524990][1:0x7f3937620a80], connection: __posix_open_file, 715: /data/db/WiredTiger.wt: handle-open: open: Operation not permitted Raw: [1557160106:524990][1:0x7f3937620a80], connection: __posix_open_file, 715: /data/db/WiredTiger.wt: handle-open: open: Operation not permitted
2019-05-06T16:28:26.544+0000 E STORAGE  [initandlisten] WiredTiger error (17) [1557160106:544574][1:0x7f3937620a80], connection: __posix_open_file, 715: /data/db/WiredTiger.wt: handle-open: open: File exists Raw: [1557160106:544574][1:0x7f3937620a80], connection: __posix_open_file, 715: /data/db/WiredTiger.wt: handle-open: open: File exists
2019-05-06T16:28:26.548+0000 I STORAGE  [initandlisten] WiredTiger message unexpected file WiredTiger.wt found, renamed to WiredTiger.wt.1
2019-05-06T16:28:26.549+0000 E STORAGE  [initandlisten] WiredTiger error (1) [1557160106:549461][1:0x7f3937620a80], connection: __posix_open_file, 715: /data/db/WiredTiger.wt: handle-open: open: Operation not permitted Raw: [1557160106:549461][1:0x7f3937620a80], connection: __posix_open_file, 715: /data/db/WiredTiger.wt: handle-open: open: Operation not permitted
2019-05-06T16:28:26.561+0000 E STORAGE  [initandlisten] WiredTiger error (17) [1557160106:561653][1:0x7f3937620a80], connection: __posix_open_file, 715: /data/db/WiredTiger.wt: handle-open: open: File exists Raw: [1557160106:561653][1:0x7f3937620a80], connection: __posix_open_file, 715: /data/db/WiredTiger.wt: handle-open: open: File exists
2019-05-06T16:28:26.564+0000 I STORAGE  [initandlisten] WiredTiger message unexpected file WiredTiger.wt found, renamed to WiredTiger.wt.2
2019-05-06T16:28:26.566+0000 E STORAGE  [initandlisten] WiredTiger error (1) [1557160106:566631][1:0x7f3937620a80], connection: __posix_open_file, 715: /data/db/WiredTiger.wt: handle-open: open: Operation not permitted Raw: [1557160106:566631][1:0x7f3937620a80], connection: __posix_open_file, 715: /data/db/WiredTiger.wt: handle-open: open: Operation not permitted
2019-05-06T16:28:26.568+0000 W STORAGE  [initandlisten] Failed to start up WiredTiger under any compatibility version.
2019-05-06T16:28:26.568+0000 F STORAGE  [initandlisten] Reason: 1: Operation not permitted
2019-05-06T16:28:26.568+0000 F -        [initandlisten] Fatal Assertion 28595 at src/mongo/db/storage/wiredtiger/wiredtiger_kv_engine.cpp 704
2019-05-06T16:28:26.568+0000 F -        [initandlisten]

***aborting after fassert() failure
```

Comment: I'm able to get it to work by doing this:
docker volume create --name=mongodata
docker run --name mongodb -v mongodata:/data/db -d -p 27017:27017 mongo

Reference: https://blog.jeremylikness.com/mongodb-on-windows-in-minutes-with-docker-3e412f076762

If anybody has a different/better way; I'm leaving open for now.

Answer (score 0):

VirtualBox Shared Folders are not supported by [mongodb](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/administration/production-notes/#fsync-on-directories).

> IMPORTANT
>
> MongoDB requires a filesystem that supports fsync() on directories.
>   For example, HGFS and Virtual Box’s shared folders do not support this
>   operation.

In case you are using Docker Desktop, When you install Docker Desktop on Windows, it requires and automatically enables Hyper-V, a hypervisor from Microsoft. Hyper-V replaces your Windows OS as the host on the computer, and your Windows OS becomes a virtual machine.

Answer (score 0):

I had this " ***aborting after fassert() failure " running MongoDB on Windows.

My log included:

```
log file journal\wiredtiger log.0000000007 corrupted: bad magic number 1869181810: wt_try_salvage: database corruption detected
```

I tried many things, but the only way to solve this problem was deleting all files on \mongodb\data\journal folder and restarting MongoDB.

No data was lost.